# No HDMI output from NP-RV409-A02MY

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card, hdmi, samsung-laptop

I've installed windows 8.1 (32-bit) on my laptop, which came shipped with windows 7 and I've installed the necessary drivers from a DVD that came with my laptop. The VGA output works fine but I'm having trouble getting the HDMI output from my laptop, the problem is my LED display broke and I have a HDMI only display which is my TV. I retried installing the graphics card driver again but that didn't work out. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure the cable & HDMI socket is working?

Comment: Cable is working, except the TV socket, I'm not sure if the HDMI port in my laptop is damaged or not